# How to dump contents of MemoryCache to a file

Tags: c#, caching

I want to dump the contents of `MemoryCache` object to a file for debugging purpose.

How can I do this?

**Code:**

```
private static readonly MemoryCache OutputCache = new MemoryCache("output-cache");    

public static void DumpMemoryCacheToFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            IFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

            bf.Serialize(fileStream, OutputCache);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

But this code gives me a runtime error saying "Unable to serialize MemoryCache".

Comment: You need to do it manually. `MemoryCache` isn't serializable. Btw you can't find anything  helpful even though you managed to dump it using `BinaryFormatter`. It will not be in readable format.

Comment: <off>you should not manually call `fileStream.Close()` method with `using` statement cause it is designed to automatically dispose (and thus close) `fileStream` object</off>

Answer (score 2):

```
var memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
var allObjects = memoryCache.ToDictionary(
    cachedObject => cachedObject.Key,
    cachedObject => cachedObject.Value
);
var contentsAsJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allObjects, Formatting.Indented);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\\myCacheContents.txt", contentsAsJson);
```

This assumes a very simple cache where the objects can be serialized easily (i.e. don't contain self-referencing objects) and we don't care about locking the cache while we're iterating its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to just dump the keys using this bit of code. Used json to serialize.

```
  public static void DumpMemoryCacheToFile(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var file = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
            {
                foreach (var item in OutputCache)
                {
                    string line = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Key);
                    file.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
```

Dumping all the objects in the cache would create a seriously large file, cluttered with content. The above was suffient for my needs.